# Validation check to see if item on list exists c#

Tags: c#, list, validation

I'm trying to perform a validation check on my list in C#. The list contains a username and hashed password. It looks like:

```
Shaun,ewoaih3243nfeiwo
John, fewafwea231232
Alex, fhi34325325325
```

So for example Shaun is the `Username` and `ewoaih3243nfeiwo` is the `password`. I am reading this list in from a database in the function Read.

Here is my code:

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> List = Read();

        label3.Text = null;
        textBox2.Text = null;

        string Username = textBox1.Text;
        string Password = textBox2.Text;
        String hashPassword = passHash.HashPass(Password);



        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {

            if (List[i].Contains(Username))
            {
                if (List[i].Contains(hashPassword))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome, " + textBox1.Text + ". Logging in...", "Welcome");
                    Form.ActiveForm.Hide();
                    Main.FrontWindow Start = new Main.FrontWindow();
                    Start.ShowDialog();
                }

                else
                {
                    label3.Text = "Username and password do not match.";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = "User does not exist";
            }
        }

    }
```

However, when I fill in the text boxes and run I always get the result that the user does not exist, even though it quite clearly does. For example when I input Shaun and an incorrect password it should say Username and Password do not match when it says instead User does not exist.

EDIT: Here is how I am creating the dictionary

```
public Dictionary<string, string> Read()
    {
        string username;
        string password;

        string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\A2 Computing\C# Programming Project\Database1.accdb";
        string SelectQuery = "SELECT Username, Password FROM users";
        OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(SelectQuery, Connection);
        Command.Connection.Open();

        OleDbDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        List<string> usernameList  = new List<string>();
        List<string> passwordList = new List<string>();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            username = (string)Reader["Username"];
            string usernameAdd = Convert.ToString(username);
            usernameList.Add(usernameAdd);

            password = (string)Reader["Password"];
            string passwordAdd = Convert.ToString(password);
            passwordList.Add(passwordAdd);
        }

        var userDictionary = usernameList.Zip(passwordList, (u, p) => new { u, p })
            .ToDictionary(x => x.u, x => x.p);

        var userList = userDictionary.ToList();
            listBox1.DataSource = userList;

        return userDictionary;

    }
```

Comment: Perhaps make sure that you're trimming user input via the text box? Any white-space characters would cause them not to be matched. Also, I would dump the contents of whatever your Read() method produces, just to do a quick sanity check and make sure that you SHOULD be getting a match when iterating through the list.

Comment: Do the contents of list have a known format?  That is you have one example with just a comma between the name and hashed password and another with a comma and a space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really separate your username and password.
Please use a `Dictionary<string, string>`.

Also, do not use a for-loop and then check if it `Contains()` the item. That would just be absurd!

You can do something as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> namesPasswords = Read(); 

// ... hashing, etc.

if(namesPasswords.Keys.Contains(Username))
    if(namesPasswords[Username].Equals(hashPassword))
        // Welcome...
    else
        // Error...
```

Comment: This is a good choice,  my answer tries to preserve your original design, but this will produce better results in the long run.

Comment: Thanks @chutzzz however I am having problems with the Equals function, it seems to disallow the correct input even though it is correct. why might I encounter this problem?

Comment: you're welcome @GeorgeBoulton .. for your question, please show us the watch values of `namesPasswords[Username]` and the `hashPassword` so we can verify. is it compiling, by the way?

Comment: @chutzzz it is compiling. the dictionary I am creating an entry would look like this [John, weoh232434]

Comment: how about the `hashPassword`? is it the same on upon visual inspection? try trimming both the dictionary value and the hashPassword before comparison

Comment: `namesPasswords[Username].Trim().Equals(hashPassword.Trim())`

Comment: Edited my original question to show creating the dictionary

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72084/discussion-between-george-boulton-and-ian-chu-te).

Comment: @GeorgeBoulton okay then :)

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it all wrong. Instead of checking the list for the username you are checking each element wether is contains the username or not. So if the last item in the list isnt the username that the user has entered in the textbox then it would give you the result that you are getting.

What you are doing isnt preferred you should instead user a `Dictionary<string, string>` OR `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` to save your username and password.

though what you have done isn't preferred still you can add the specified breakpoints to make it work correctly. The idea is that if the first `IF` finds a username then the loop shouldn't continue and should instead break doing the stuff it is supposed to do.

```
for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {

            if (List[i].Contains(Username))
            {
                if (List[i].Contains(hashPassword))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(
                     "Welcome, 
                     " + textBox1.Text + ". Logging in...", "Welcome");

                    Form.ActiveForm.Hide();
                    Main.FrontWindow Start = new Main.FrontWindow();
                    Start.ShowDialog();
                }

                else
                {
                    label3.Text = "Username and password do not match.";
                }
              break;
            }
            else
            {
                label3.Text = "User does not exist";
            }
        }
```

Alternatively you can also do this (thought not preferred at all).

 *Note im just writing this code here please check for compilation errors.*

```
var user = List
.Select(e=>e.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmpty).Select(a=>
new
 {
  Username = a[0].Trim(), 
  Password=a[1].Trim()
 }))
.Where(o=>o.Username = Username /*username entered by the user*/)
.SingleOrDefault();

if(user!=null)
{
  if(user.Password == Password /*password entered by the user*/) {/*Valid User*/}
  else{/*Invalid password OR Username*/}
}
else {/*User does not exist*/}
```

Comment: Don't run your checks through a for-loop. List<String>.Contains will iterate through the contents of your list already.